# How to make MIDI file from notes with Flute instrument in Python (music21 library)

Tags: python, midi, music21

I have some notes and what I want is create the MIDI file with Flute instrument. But what happens is that the output MIDI file plays Piano, instead of Flute. I tried other instruments, but it's always the same, Piano. What is going on?

```
(...)
new_note = note.Note(pattern)
new_note.offset = offset
new_note.storedInstrument = instrument.Piano()
output_notes.append(new_note)
(...)
midi_stream = stream.Stream(output_notes)
midi_stream.write('midi', fp='output.midi')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [documentation](http://web.mit.edu/music21/doc/moduleReference/moduleNote.html), the only class with a `storedInstrument` property is `note.Unpitched`.

And:

> The `Unpitched` object does not currently do anything and should not be used.

Anyway, the `testMidiProgramChangeA`/`B` functions in `music21/midi/translate.py` show how this is to be done: just add the instrument object into the `Stream` before the `Note`s that should use it:

```
output_notes.append(instrument.Flute())
new_note = ...
output_notes.append(new_note)
...
```