# Music21 make an MIDI stream sound like a particular instrument

Tags: python, python-3.x, midi, music21

I am using the Music21 python module for a project. The output of my code generates a MIDI file. I want this MIDI file to sound like a guitar, but it sounds like a Piano. I saw a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55170188/how-to-make-midi-file-from-notes-with-flute-instrument-in-python-music21-librar) which said I should add instrument.Guitar() before the notes in my output notes sequence.

But still the notes are being played like a keyboard.

This is the code which generates the output notes based on a sequence of input notes:

```
for pattern in in_notes:
    # pattern is a chord
    if len(self.intervals)<1:
        self.set_intervals()
    if ('.' in pattern) or pattern.isdigit():
        notes_in_chord = pattern.split('.')
        notes = []
        for current_note in notes_in_chord:
            new_note = note.Note(int(current_note))
            notes.append(new_note)
        new_chord = chord.Chord(notes)
        new_chord.offset = offset
        output_notes.append(instrument.ElectricGuitar())
        output_notes.append(new_chord)
    # pattern is a note
    else:
        new_note = note.Note(pattern)
        new_note.offset = offset
        output_notes.append(instrument.ElectricGuitar())
        output_notes.append(new_note)
    # increase offset each iteration so that notes do not stack
    offset += self.intervals[0]
    self.intervals.pop(0)
```

And the part which generates the output MIDI file:

```
midi_stream = stream.Stream(output_notes)
key = midi_stream.analyze('key')
i=interval.Interval(key.tonic,pitch.Pitch(self.key))
midi = midi_stream.transpose(i)
midi.write('midi', fp=f'{self.file_name}.midi')
```

How do I make it sound like a guitar?
It seems to work if I try to change the instrument to a violin with `output_notes.append(instrument.Violin())` but not for any of the Guitars:- Guitar(), AcousticGuitar(), ElectricGuitar()

Comment: The instrument needs to be added only once. Anyway, does it work without the `transpose` call?

Comment: No, it doesnt work without the transpose() either

Comment: A little update, it works when I do ```output_notes.append(instrument.Violin())```